# Add room number to postal address?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, address

Let's say I live in the student dormitory. If I'm writing the address should I add my room number so that a parcel can be delivered into my post box?

Comment: If you care about privacy of data, you might ensure given postal address is made-up.

Comment: You might also want to consider: [What is the address format I should use for sending a letter/mail?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/28167/9551)

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it's usual in dorms and advisable if you want to make sure that the parcel is delivered to you and not someone else!

As already pointed out, you can put it in the same line as the street. According to the DIN standard 5008 for addressing, you should use space, double-slash, space to separate it from the house number:

> [Vorname] [Nachname] 
> Straßenname Str. 123 // Zi. 123 
> 12345 [Stadt]

The alternative is to use a separate line for it, but then **before** the street (that means between name and street):

> [Vorname] [Nachname] 
> Zi. 123 
> Straßenname Str. 123 
> 12345 [Stadt]

Also note that there is no comma between postal code and city and "Str." is always capitalized if it is a separate word ("Goethestr." but "Lange Str."). The country should only be indicated on international mailings.

Comment: "make sure that the parcel is delivered to you and not someone else" - this statement is quite misleading. Unless the parcel is sent with some delivery restriction such as "eigenhändig", adding a room number will only clarify where the recipient of the parcel is located, not who the parcel will be handed over to.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you should add your room number. Because a postman has no time to search your name among 500 others under same address.

Just another abbreviation: Zi. - because the exact location has to be found by local postman, not by sender's post office.

> [Vorname] [Nachname] 
>   Budapester Str. 24 / Zi. 123 
>   01069 Dresden 
>   Germany

Depending of the address fields of the sender it is also possible to use a new line, I used both ways in my past:

> [Vorname] [Nachname] 
>   [Straße] [Hausnummer] 
>   Zi. 123 
>   [PLZ] [Stadt] 
>   [Germany]

-> country "Germany" only if post is sent from another country.

Comment: I would write the room number on a separate line so it is clearly recognizable.

Comment: It's *Allemagne*, not *Germany* for international letters and parcels, as the offical post language is French.

Comment: @Janka English was added as a working language in 1994. Anyway, it should read  "ALLEMAGNE" or "GERMANY" rather than "Allemagne" or "Germany".

Comment: "Because a postman has no time to search your name among 500 others under same address." - well, let's say it's a courtesy. It is by no means guaranteed that there *are* any room/apartment numbers in a larger building. Thus, often, a postman has no other choice than to take the time to search for a name among many others. But if there are room numbers, it is very welcome to make the postman's life a bit easier.

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible/common to use *z.H. = zu Händen* (attn:, FAO = for the attention of), like so:

> Name of the student's dormatory
>  z.H. Herrn/Frau (Mr./Mrs.) forname
> surname, Zi. 123
>
> the street's name 12
>  12345 Name of the city/village
>  Country

Comment: Welcome on the German SE! Look, how better your answer seems after a little formatting. :-)

Comment: @peterh - Reinstate Monica: Thank you for supporting and the advice! :-)